# How to use WooCommerce is_shop conditional tag excluding searchs results

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements

I have a function that uses the conditional tag is_shop.

The function is intended to display a widget on the shop page only.
However, it also returns the widget when a search is performed.

Is there a way to only return it on the shop main page.

My code is:

```
function cs_beforeproducts_sidebar() {
    if( is_shop() ){
        get_sidebar( 'aboveproducts' );
    } else {
}
}
```

I've tried using is_page as well with no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WordPress `is_search()` as a conditional tag like:

```
function cs_beforeproducts_sidebar() {
    // Only shop and not a search
    if( is_shop() && ! is_search() ){
        get_sidebar( 'aboveproducts' );
    } else {
        // something else
    }
}
```

Or as a product search adds **'s'** query variable in URL, you can try to use:

```
function cs_beforeproducts_sidebar() {
    // Only shop and not search
    if( is_shop() && ! isset($_GET['s']) ){
        get_sidebar( 'aboveproducts' );
    } else {
        // something else
    }
}
```

Both works.